# How do I access an object inside of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

This is the object that is being returned.

```
Object: 
    contributors_enabled: false
    created_at: "Sat Apr 18 02:20:51 +0000 2009"
    ...
    status: Object
    ...
    verified: false
```

As you can see there are 2 objects. The parent and then the object inside that called "status".

In javascript, how does one go about accessing the "status" object.

I have tried `object.status` which returns null.

Real Code:

```
function get_data( $id ) { 
    global $tmhOAuth; 
    $code = $tmhOAuth->request( 'POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/users/lookup.json', ''), array( 'user_id' => $id ) );
    if ( $code == 200 ) {
        $data = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);
        return $data; 
    } else { 
        outputError($tmhOAuth);
    }   
} 

if ( !empty( $_POST ) && !is_null( $_POST ) ) { 
    extract( $_POST ); //imports $id; 
    $data = get_data($id); 
    exit(json_encode($data)); 
} 


$.post( 
    '/twitauth/app.php', 
    data, 
    function( response ) { 
        console.log( response ); 
    }, 
   'json'
);
```

Comment: Can we have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: I'm guessing that's just pseudo code, as that does'nt really look like a valid JS object ?

Comment: Is this one of those CoffeeScripts again? or pseudocode?

Comment: It is a json encoded response that you get when you do a post request to get a user data object, which contains the status object.

Comment: @Ankur before anything else... did you parse the JSON? can you put the **actual** script so we can test it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to post the actual code, because either of these two should work:

```
object.status
object["status"]
```

If those aren't working, then you have defined the object incorrectly somehow, or the object within the object is private.

Comment: *did you mean `object["status"]`?*

Comment: I would also recommend checking for the existence of the property via hasOwnProperty and whether it is defined via "== undefined".

Comment: Ayup, Joseph. @achinda99 always a good idea to see if an object exists before trying to use it, that's for sure. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference n layers of objects using the `.` operator, no problem.

Here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EcC7B/1/)

```
var myobj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2
};

var foobar = {
    'foo' : 'bar',
    'status' : myobj    
    };

console.log(foobar.status.a);
```